# Exclude rows starting from certain characters using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have sql query like below which excludes rows starting from letter x

```
select * from table where name like 'x%'
```

How do i write it same using Linq?

I tried using

```
 var query = (from a in _tableARepository.AsQueryable()
              join b in _tableBRepository.AsQueryable()
                   on a.Id equals b.Id
              where a.name.contains("x") 
              select new { a, b});
```

But this includes everything with "x"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a.name is a string, just use `where a.name.StartsWith("x")`.