# Linq to Sql NLSSORT

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, nls-sort

Just wondering if there is a way to call NLSSort through linq.
Actually to be more specific, when I call my OrderBy clauses in Linq, 
I want them To be ordered Alphabetically but Ignoring special characters such as ".'/@

Does anyone know of an extension method or how to write an extension method to do so?

-Thanks

Comment: Does this answer helps you?


[See this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403544/exclude-rows-starting-from-certain-characters-using-linq

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby.